# Suspend a call until a value is set

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want class `UploadWorker` to retrieve a value from class `Manager`, but that value may not yet be ready in `Manager`. So I want class `UploadWorker` to wait until that value is set.

```
class UploadWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters):
       Worker(appContext, workerParams) {
   override fun doWork(): Result {

       Manager.isReady()

       return Result.success()
   }
}

object Manager {
      private lateinit var isReady

      fun initialize(context: Context, myData: MyData) {
          ...
          isReady = true
      }
      
      suspend fun isReady() {

          if(::isReady.isInitialized()             
             return isReady
          else // wait here until initialized 
      }    
}
```

In the else if I could somehow `suspend` or wait until my `MyApplication` class calls `initialize()`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CompletableDeferred` is quite handy for situations like this.

Your code would probably look something like this:

```
object Manager {
    private val initialized = CompletableDeferred<Unit>()

    fun initialize(context: Context, myData: MyData) {
        ...
        initialized.complete(Unit)
    }

    suspend fun awaitInitialized() {
        initialized.await()
        // initialization is done at this point
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StateFlow` to deliver status of initialization:

```kotlin
val isReady = MutableStateFlow(false)

// to wait:
if (isReady.value) return true
else isReady.first { it }  // it == true

// to notify:
isReady.value = true
```

Although StateFlows are quite lightweight, but if you want to do it more lighter but in a ugly way (using coroutine internals directly):

```kotlin
val conts = mutableListOf<Continuation<Boolean>>()

private lateinit var isReady = false
    set(value) {
        if (value) conts.forEach { it.resume(true) }.also { conts.clear() }
        field = value
    }

// to wait:
if (isReady) return true
else suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    conts.add(cont)

    invokeOnCancellation { conts.remove(cont) }
}

// to notify:
isReady = true
```